# NextJS Serverless functions exceeded 50megabytes, but includes many unnecessary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-lambda, serverless, vercel

It looks like Vercels build pipeline for NextJS likes to include a lot of unnecessary files for serverless functions, after some reading I found there was an 'outputFileTraceExcludes' I can use.

I added it to my next.config like follows:

```
const toExclude = ['node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0', 
                  './node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0', 
                  'node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/**/*',
                  './node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/**/*',
                  './node_modules/**/*',
                  'node_modules/**/*',
                  './node_modules/*',
                  './public/**/*',
                  '/public/**/*',
                  'public',
                  'node_modules',
                  './node_modules'
                ]

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    outputFileTracingExcludes: {
      'api/test': toExclude,
    }
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: false,
  },
  compiler: {
    emotion: true,
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      issuer: {
        and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/],
      },
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    return config;
  },
}
```

For a function that lives in [url]/api/test.

When vercel builds it however it still includes node_modules, et all and the function that does nothing balloons to over 50 megabytes.

What could I be doing wrong here?